# Sample consecutive groups of elements without replacement

Tags: r, sampling

I have the following data frame

```
ddd<-data.frame(minutes=1:15,positive=c(0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1))
```

Using sampling, I would like to find what is the probability that in *k* trials sampling from consecutive intervals of  ddd$minutes of *j* length at least one `ddd$positive` will appear. For example for *j=2* (2 minute intervals) the sample space will be
`ddd$minutes[1:2, 2:3, 3:4, 4:5, 5:6, 6:7, …:14:15]`. However, if in the first of the k trials the interval `ddd$minutes[1:2]` gets sampled (one success), then the interval `ddd$minutes[2:3]` is removed from the sampled space (before the next random sampling), as the two groups intersect (`ddd$minutes[2]` exists in both).

This is not a simple a matter of sampling without replacement,as not only the sampled but also all groups that intersect with the already sampled should be removed from the sample space before the next sampling takes place.

**EDIT (comment from Tim P)**: `length(ddd$minutes)` can be somewhere between 1000-1200; *k* between 1 and 16. *j* between 1 and 30

**EDIT2 (comment by Thierry)**

I am giving an example, following a comment and answer by Thierry

```
ddd<-data.frame(minutes=1:15,positive=c(0,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1)) 
l=3;k=3
```

Sample Space S0 (before the first sampling): 
S0:{1:3, 2:4, 3:5, 4:6, 5:7, 6:8, 7:9, 8:10, 9:11, 10:12, 11:13, 12:14, 13:15}
length of S0 is 13 (n-k+1)

First trial out of k: the element 8:10 gets selected.

S1 is then redefined as S0 but without the elements 6:8, 7:9, 8:10, 9:11, 10:12, that intersect with the sampled element 8:10

So, S1 is:{ 1:3, 2:4, 3:5, 4:6, 5:7, 11:13, 12:14, 13:15}

Second trial out of k: element 4:6 gets selected

S2 is redefined as S1 without the elements 2:4, 3:5, 4:6, 5:7,

So, S2:{1:3, 11:13, 12:14, 13:15}

and so on until the *k*th sample. Eventually my goals is to run this kind of sampling a lot of times and see what is the probability that at least one ddd$success will appear will get picked up.

Comment: Hi, interesting problem. What do we know about k relative to j and n = length(minutes)? I ask because in your j = 2 example, if 2:3 and 5:6 are picked then no other selections are possible. If you picked those first, you could never extend to a selection for k = 3, say.

Comment: Very good comment. n can go up to 1000, maybe 1200. k assumes values from 1 to 16. j is 1 to 30.

Comment: Are you most interested in a solution for n in the range 1000 to 1200 then, rather than a small case like n=15? I have an idea in mind...

Comment: The ddd i mention in my question is just an example to make my case. The problem i try to solve takes n anything between 300 and 1200, usually between 1000 and 1200. Thanks a lot for your effort and time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a recursive function.

```
n <- 1000
j <- 10
set.seed(12345)
ddd <- data.frame(minutes=seq_len(n), positive = rbinom(n, 1, 0.1))
dataset <- ddd
k <- 16
sillySampling <- function(dataset, k, j){
  i <- sample(nrow(dataset) - j + 1, 1)
  thisSample <- max(dataset$positive[i - 1 + seq_len(j)])
  if(k > 1){
    toRemove <- i + -j:j
    toRemove <- toRemove[toRemove >= 1 & toRemove <= nrow(dataset)]
    thisSample <- c(thisSample, sillySampling(dataset[-toRemove, ], k  = k - 1, j = j))
  }
  return(thisSample)
}
rowMeans(replicate(100, {
  sapply(1:16, function(k){
    sum(sillySampling(ddd, k, 10)) / k
  })
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rather aggregate the dataset to samples of k minutes. And then sample the aggregated dataset. What more information do you expect from your kind of sampling? Your way of sampling will throw away more data.

```
n <- 1000
j <- 10
set.seed(12345)
ddd <- data.frame(minutes=seq_len(n), positive = rbinom(n, 1, 0.1))
ddd$group <- ddd$minutes %/% j
AGR <- aggregate(ddd$positive, by = ddd[, "group", drop = FALSE], FUN = max)
rowMeans(replicate(1000, {
    sapply(1:16, function(k){
        sum(sample(AGR$x, k, replace = FALSE)) / k
    })
}))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it is very important that the sample space is reevaluated before the next sampling and to reject elements from the sample space that intersect with the previously sampled elements. In your answer the sample space of ddd has a length of 1000/10=100. This is not correct. The sample space of ddd should be n-j+1 (see question). And the whole purpose is to before each sampling to revealuate the sample space and reject elements that intersect with the previously selected samples. This is the whole purpose. Any ideas?

Comment: please to that your sample space is NOT n-j+1. That is only the case for the first sample. Assume one sample at 1:j and one sample at j + 1 + (1:j). The position j + 1 does not occur in the samples but cannot be selected due to your rules. Suppose that the second sample is at 2 * j - 1 + (1:j). Then all points from j + 1 to 2 * j - 1 are no longer available.

Comment: My sample space is n / j. Your effective sample space is n / j when there is no gap between samples. In the worst case it will be n / (2 * j -1). Your effective sample space will never be larger than n / j.

Comment: I agree with you, but your solution does not answer my question. The initial sample space S0 (before the 1st sample) IS n-j+1 (all the possible j-consecutive combinations of n). After the first sample, the sample space is redefined, to the reduced S1<S0. The elements S0 intersecting with the first sample are rejected and also as you say some more elements of S0 will not be available. This is the reduced sample space S1 before the second sample, and so on. This is not binomial trials and not hypergeometric trials. Its something different. Thats why I try to solve it programmatically.